# WebGL: INVALID_VALUE when using tf.browser.fromPixels to convert a local image

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, webgl

After executing the following codes:

```
  var myImage = new Image(48,48);
  myImage.src = '1.png';
  document.body.appendChild(myImage);
  console.log(tf.browser.fromPixels(myImage));
```

A warning message showed up:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: no image
```

and the conversion seemed to be failed, although the image is successfully loaded and showed up on the html page. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normaly you'd need to wait for the image to load.

```
const myImage = new Image();
myImage.onload = function() {
  console.log(tf.browser.fromPixels(myImage));
};
myImage.src = '1.png';
document.body.appendChild(myImage);
```